# How do Gilman reagents open epoxides?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

From what it looks like, Gilman reagents are good nucleophiles, and will attack at the less-substituted side of an asymmetric alkane because Gilman reagents don't necessarily need a substantial amount of partial positive character at the site of attack.

However, don't strong nucleophiles open epoxides in an SN2 like manner? Where's the inversion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first reaction, the reaction doesn't take place at a stereocenter, so there's no way to observe the inversion.

In the second reaction, the stereochemistry in the product is R, R. The Gilman reagent approaches opposite the C-O bond. After bond rotation, we see the product in the indicated conformation.

[image]

Comment: First one or second one? @jerepierre

Comment: @Dissenter I've clarified my answer to address both examples.

Comment: but how do Gilmans open epoxides? From the less substituted side ... but does opening proceed with inversion or retention of stereochemistry?

Comment: @Dissenter The reaction goes with inversion.

Comment: you were wrong; the second product is RR.

Comment: @Dissenter You're right, it's RR. However it's still inversion.